# clang: error: linker command failed: duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker-errors

In my app i am getting this error:

> linker command failed with exit code 1

```
/Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BalirajaTractor-cfrcwepounrfzmcqcpnfxpsftfdg/Build/Intermediates/BalirajaTractor.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BalirajaTractor.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MenuViewController.o
duplicate symbol _areaArray in:
/Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BalirajaTractor-cfrcwepounrfzmcqcpnfxpsftfdg/Build/Intermediates/BalirajaTractor.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BalirajaTractor.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AddProductViewController.o

/Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BalirajaTractor-cfrcwepounrfzmcqcpnfxpsftfdg/Build/Intermediates/BalirajaTractor.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BalirajaTractor.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MenuViewController.o
ld: 8 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
```

> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: are you having `areaArr` variable in the global space in both viewcontroller ?

Answer (score 1):

I had encountered a similar error recently because I had `#import class.m` instead of `#import class.h`. Check whether you have made that mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same problem with Xcode 8.1.When I use NSManagedObject Subclass to create entities. I got 4 files `Entity+CoreDataClass.h`, `Entity+CoreDataClass.m`, `EntityCoreDataProperties.h`, `Entity+COreDataProperties.m`.

When I run the code , I got the error.

When I delete the `Entity+CoreDataClass.m` in *Targets>>Build Phases>>Complies Sources*, the error is gone.

Really hope can help someone.